# Change the Range of Year Values within Date Type to Accommodate Possible Birth Years Rails, Simple_Form, HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, simple-form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@model) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input birthday %>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The default months and days work just fine, but the range of selection for years is too slim.  Default only goes from 2010 - 2020.  How do I change it so it ranges from, say, 1930 - current year?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@model) do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :birthday, start_year: Date.today.year - 110, end_year: Date.today.year %>

     <div class="form-actions">
         <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

This gives the possible year selection from current year to 110 years ago.

Found here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select